# cannot resolve symbol junit

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit

Every time a reload a project, my junit gets the "Cannot resolve junit" error. The tests seem to work fine before. This usually happens when the project is closed and restarted in Intellij.

This is the dependency

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Here is the import statement

```
import org.junit.{Before, Ignore, Test}
```

Here is the gradle settings. I also tried gradle for build and run, still not working.

[image]

The code builds successfully, however it says junit cannot be resolved.
Any pointers are helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to share you project sample?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Try File | New | Project from Existing Sources... action and select build.gradle(kts) file to import from. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I made a dummy change to gradle and rebuilded the entire project. Thus solved it, but still not sure what could have caused this issue